# How to handle compressed response with JSforce in NodeJS

Tags: api, integration

How might we uncompress responses using JSforce? I'm using [Connect REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_what_is_chatter_connect.htm).

I have tried to decompress the content of String with Zlib (because the header `Content-Encoding` is set to `gzip`) and decode as UTF, moving into a Buffer and decompressing but none of it worked (for Zlib I keep getting an error like `incorrect header check`).

This is the code with JSforce as of today:

```
import jsforce from 'jsforce'

const webStoreId = '0ZE...';
const communityUrl = 'https://myDomainName--sandboxName.sandbox.my.site.com/siteSuffix';
const accessToken = '00D...';
let conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    instanceUrl: communityUrl,
    accessToken: accessToken
  });

const searchTerm = 'vita';
const pageIndex = 0;

const response = await conn.request(
    {
        url: `/services/data/v54.0/commerce/webstores/${webStoreId}/search/product-search`,
        method: 'post', 
        body: `
        {
            "searchTerm": "${searchTerm}",
            "includePrices": true,
            "fields": ["Name", "StockKeepingUnit", "Description"], 
            "page": ${pageIndex},
            "pageSize": 1
        }
        `,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    }
);
```

The response contains something like `'\x1F�\b\x00\x0`.

I was able to make it work with a regular request using Axio library but this does not seems to benefit from other features that JSforce can provide:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const communityUrl = 'https://myDomainName--sandboxName.sandbox.my.site.com/siteSuffix';
const webStoreId = '0ZE...';
const searchTerm = 'vita';
const accessToken = '00D...';

let response = await axios
  .post(
      `${communityUrl}/services/data/v54.0/commerce/webstores/${webStoreId}/search/product-search`,
      {
        "searchTerm": searchTerm, 
        "includePrices": true, 
        "fields": ["Name", "StockKeepingUnit", "Description"], 
        "page": pageIndex, 
        "pageSize": 1
      },
      {
        headers: { 
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    );
```

The `response.data` then contains the JSON response.

Worth knowing that if I disable uncompressing on Axios, I get the same result as JSforce. And this is not happening in all instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem that can save others countless hours.

I added `gzip: true` on the request object. It works because the request object is sent to the request module with its attributes.

The source of the answer shared by Yamyle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28583320/8255460

See the `gzip: true` after the `headers`:

```
import jsforce from 'jsforce'

const webStoreId = '0ZE...';
const communityUrl = 'https://myDomainName--sandboxName.sandbox.my.site.com/siteSuffix';
const accessToken = '00D...';
let conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    instanceUrl: communityUrl,
    accessToken: accessToken
  });

const searchTerm = 'vita';
const pageIndex = 0;

const response = await conn.request(
    {
        url: `/services/data/v54.0/commerce/webstores/${webStoreId}/search/product-search`,
        method: 'post', 
        body: `
        {
            "searchTerm": "${searchTerm}",
            "includePrices": true,
            "fields": ["Name", "StockKeepingUnit", "Description"], 
            "page": ${pageIndex},
            "pageSize": 1
        }
        `,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
        gzip: true
    }
);
```

Note: this is required because because as stated on [request documentation](https://github.com/request/request#examples):

> For backwards-compatibility, response compression is not supported by default. To accept gzip-compressed responses, set the `gzip` option to `true`. Note that the body data passed through `request` is automatically decompressed while the response object is unmodified and will contain compressed data if the server sent a compressed response.

Answer (score 0):

`gzip`, `zlib`, and `zip` are three separate file formats that are incompatible with each other. `zlib` should be able to handle it, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22311297/2132791) on Stack Overflow but needs to be told that it is supposed to be using `gzip` ([RFC 1952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt)) rather than the native `zlib` ([RFC 1950](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1950.txt)). Instead, consider just using `gzip` directly, you can install it with `npm i --save gzip`.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for ther reminder. I installed `gzip` and it seems that is blank now. I tried with `node-gzip` (i.e. `const decompressed = await ungzip(response);`) and I still got the incorrect header check. I'm sure I am missing something but I cannot find it yet.

Comment: @JefersonChaves Weird, because it should be a gzip stream. Based on what you said, I guessed that the first two bytes are actually `1f 8b`, which, according to Wikipedia at least, should be a tar zip. Maybe try saving the contents directly to a file and try using various utilities on it until it works. The fact that Axios understands the compression but jsforce does not, it may also be a setting you need to check in jsforce, or maybe a bug?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I also tried to `options: { gzip: true }` because apparently `jsforce` used `request` module and it should have native capability to uncompress it, but this makes no difference.

Comment: I was able to patch the prototype of `JSforce` (ugh) to force gzip compression:
```
const originalJsForceTransport = jsforceTransport.prototype._getHttpRequestModule;
  jsforceTransport.prototype._getHttpRequestModule = function() {
    const originalHttpRequest = originalJsForceTransport();

    // add gzip at defaults - request library can auto-uncompress it
    const modifiedHttpRequest = originalHttpRequest.defaults({gzip: true});
    return modifiedHttpRequest;
  }
```

Comment: So, it seems that is more missing feature on `JSforce` because `request` module does not deflate responses by default (that on their [documentation](https://github.com/request/request): For backwards-compatibility, response compression is not supported by default. To accept gzip-compressed responses, set the gzip option to true.).

Comment: @JefersonChaves Nice find. I did try a search myself, didn't find it, so that's good to know.